# How to Join table with Itself to produce 2 duplicate rows using FetchXML

Tags: ssrs-2012, fetchxml

I'm trying to create duplicate records in my result set in order for me to show row more than once in a report. Some rows need to show up in multiple groups. My answer to this is to have **FetchXML** return dupes and then ill just create group filters to solve my problem. If you guys have better approach to my problem let me know. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You must use subreport for this case and pass parameters into it from main report.